# Strip of absolute path from files in a list

Tags: cmake

I want to get a list with all files in a directory and its subdirectories, The problem is, I only get them with their absolute path. How can I remove the absolute path? I tried this without success:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE parts chapters/*.tex)

message(STATUS "Remove absolute part of the paths")
foreach (_parts ${parts})
    file(RELATIVE_PATH ${_parts} "/home/user/latex_project/main" ${_parts})
endforeach()
```

Comment: `get_filename_component()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct usage of commands:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE parts chapters/*.tex)

message(STATUS "Remove absolute part of the paths")
set(rel_parts) # List of relative paths
foreach (_parts ${parts}) # Iterate over list of absolute paths
    # Obtain relative path into local variable
    file(RELATIVE_PATH _rel_parts "/home/user/latex_project/main" ${_parts})
    # Add relative path into the list
    list(APPEND rel_parts ${_rel_parts})
endforeach()
# Now variable 'rel_parts' contains list of relative paths
```

Or simply use *RELATIVE* option of `file(GLOB_RECURSE)`:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE parts RELATIVE "/home/user/latex_project/main" chapters/*.tex)
```

Comment: I didn't know about the RELATIVE option. That works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE parts chapters/*.tex)

message(STATUS "Remove absolute part of the paths")
set(_tmplist)
foreach (_parts ${parts})
    set(_tmpvar)
    get_filename_component(_tmpvar "${_parts}" NAME)
    list(APPEND _tmplist "${_tmpvar}")
endforeach()
set(parts "${_tmplist}")
```

[get_filename_component()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/get_filename_component.html)